# Checking if a word exist in a file C

Tags: c

In order to check if a word exist in a .txt file I've done the following function :

```
void checkWord (char* word){
    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char line[1000] = "";

    if(file != NULL){
        while(fgets(line, 1000, file) != NULL){

            if (strcmp(line, word) == 0){
                printf("hello");            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Yet this code **doesn't** print hello when I call : `checkWord("hello");` on the file :

```
aaaaa
hello
aaaaa
```

but **does** print hello when I call : `checkWord("hello");` on the file :

```
aaaa
hello
```

and I don't understand why.

Comment: `line` probably contains the newline character at the end.

Comment: yes I think this was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first file the string `hello` is not contained by the last line, so it is followed by a `'\n'` character. In the second fole the same string is at the end of file (so no trailing `'\n'`).

The core of the issue is that `fgets()` stops parsing when a newline character is found AND it doesn't remove that character from the returned string. For this reason an exact match is not found in the first file, when the actual string is `"hello\n"`.

In order to solve it you can either remove the trailing `'\n'` from the string read by fgets or, if the requirements allow it, search just for the presence of the substring by issuing `strstr ()`.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't see it, the end of every line except the last one in your file contains a new line character. This is represented by *\n*. When comparing elements line by line, you will have to account for the fact that most lines will have this character at the end.